# Use interpolation in bootstrap switch tag

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I implemented [Angular Bootstrap Switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-bootstrap-switch) into Angular 5 Application

So I use that switch in mat table like:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
              <switch [status]="status" [onText]="yes" [offText]="no" [onColor]="green" [offColor]="gray" [size]="normal" [disabled]="disabled"></switch>
            </mat-cell>
```

My question is how can I add interpolation value into switch `[status]`? I try like

```
 <switch [status]="{{user.activo}}" [onText]="yes" [offText]="no" [onColor]="green" [offColor]="gray" [size]="normal" [disabled]="disabled"></switch>
```

But it returns error. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is user a component's property? If so, just do `[status]="user.activo"`

Comment: iT WORKS. why it works? I'm very confussed, am new in Angular, is not suppossed I always use interpolation for values loaded in component? @ChristianBenseler

Comment: I have answered the question, with a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
[status]="user.activo"
```

You better take a read carefully at the official doc https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax; you only use interpolation ({{...}}) to `print` something. If you are going to set a value to a property, you should use `[propertyName]` and then just use a javascript blockcode (which is called `template expression`).

Note that you can also do something like this (use some logic):

```
//component
someValueFromComponent = 1;
//template
<input [value]='someValueFromComponent + 1' /> //will render an input with value = 2
```